# How do I use Cartthrob's tax by class plugin with countries?

Tags: cartthrob, tax

I'm trying to figure out how the Tax By Class plugin works. Specifically the country parameter.

I've got a set up whereby site admins can set a Tax Class in the product entry and this gets applied as an item_option using a hidden field when adding that item to the cart. This works OK so far as I've tested it.

In the tax by class settings I have 3 classes, "Standard", "Discounted", and "Zero Rated".

I have then created different tax rates in the matrix like so:- 
VAT 20% UK "Standard"
Reduced VAT 15% UK "Discounted"
Zero rated 0% UK "Zero Rated"

These all work as expected.

I then tried adding a new rate for Belgium:
VAT 21% Belgium "Standard"

[image: Cartthrob tax by class settings]

But changing the shipping country on the checkout doesn't seem to apply the new tax rate as defined in the plugin. Previously I had been using Tax By Location and the rate would changed based on shipping country set so I know that bit is working as it should and updating the customer's country info.

Am I misunderstanding how this should work or have I just set it up incorrectly? Or is it a genuine bug?

Comment: This is actually working OK. I hadn't set the "tax by shipping location" option to "yes". However this means the previously working tax by location set up has a bug since it was working fine with the setting "no".

Comment: Could you tell me how you did the "set up whereby site admins can set a Tax Class in the product entry and this gets applied as an item_option using a hidden field when adding that item to the cart".

Comment: I'm afraid I genuinely cannot remember what project this was for and I can't recall exactly what I was doing nor what I did! I have a feeling the client requirements changed so I would have ended up using the Tax by Location - Percentage plugin anyway.